# Notification or change the css on Ajax setinterval when new data pushed in

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval

Suppose I have an Ajax function that displays the new data every 5 seconds. Now, whenever the new data is pushed (displayed) I want to change the css (class="av") colour of that particular value. The ajax is currently displaying 5 rows, but I want to change the colour only of that changed value. How do I do that? many thanks

my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){

                //function to get data from database
                function getRealData(){
                    $.ajax({ 
                    url: 'test_api.php', 
                    data: "", dataType: 'json', 
                    success: function(rows) { 

                    var text = '';

                        for (var i in rows) { 

                            var row = rows[i]; 

                            var availability = row[3]; 

                            var hostName = row[2];

                            var intranet = row[6];

                            var timeRespons = row[4]; 


                            text += "<div class='box'><b>availability: </b><span class='av'>"+availability+"</span><b> hostName: </b>"+hostName+
                            "<b> intranet: </b>"+intranet+"<b> timeResponse: </b>"+timeRespons;
                            text += '<br/ ></div>';


                        }
                        $("#content").html(text);                                       
                    }
                });
                }

                //this refreshes data every 2seconds
                setInterval(getRealData, 5000);

                //call the function to display data
                getRealData();

                //notification
                function notify(){


                var avValue = $(".av").html();

            console.log(avValue);

            if(avValue == 1){
                $(".av").css({"color":"red"});
            }
        }


        setInterval(notify, 2000);

        notify();

});

</script>
```

EDIT: (this the output, and Need to change the colour of 1)

```
availability: 1 hostName: aaa intranet: vvvvv timeResponse:0.144
availability: 0 hostName: zzz intranet: rrrrr timeResponse:0.028
availability: 1 hostName: qqq intranet: eeeee timeResponse:0.160
availability: 0 hostName: eee intranet: qqqqq timeResponse:0.116
availability: 0 hostName: ttt intranet: wwwww timeResponse:0.046
availability: 0 hostName: uuu intranet: kkkkk timeResponse:0.116
```

I was also thinking to add a new class to .box when avValue == 1 and then based on that if that class exists to do something. but this doesn't work either. It is very strange. could that be something to do with async or caching ajax?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: edited with my attempts

Comment: that is fixed to .av, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to have two timers here, you can just set the style of the `.av` span when you are building it. I would add a new CSS class called `avHighlight` and then when you are building the HTML, test if `availability` is 1. If it is, then add the new `avHighlight` class.

If you do this, you can remove the `notify()` function and it's associated timer.

css

```
.avHighlight {
    color: red
}
```

Javascript

```
text += '<div class="box"><b>availability: </b>
    <span class="av ' + (availability == 1 ? 'avHighlight' : '') + '">'+availability+'</span>' + 
    '<b> hostName: </b>'+hostName+ '<b> intranet: </b>'+intranet+'<b> timeResponse:</b>'+timeRespons;
text += '<br/ ></div>';
```

Comment: I don't know no...no errors at all...just the value in console

Comment: Are the rows not getting highlighted? If I know how it's not working I can help you fix it. If you updated the CSS, you'll need to clear your browser cache to see it take effect.

Comment: where are you adding a new class "avHighlight" ?

Comment: In the second line of the javascript: `<span class="av ' + (availability === 1 ? 'avHighlight' : '') + '">'`. This uses the ternary operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: not working though, I edited my question with a suggestion :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33372/discussion-between-cfs-and-marcel)

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is something like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="av">Ajax Content</div>
    <div class="av">Ajax Content</div>
    <div class="av">Ajax Content</div>
    <div class="av">Ajax Content</div>
    <div class="av">Ajax Content</div>
    <div class="av">Ajax Content</div>
</div>
```

In the CSS you can just do:

```
.av:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

With that, the first item (the one you brought in last) will always be red. You don't need any fancy JS to do that. If bring in the items from the bottom all you have to do is use `:last-child`

**EDIT:**

If you are adding more than one row at a time, you can use the `:lt()` selector. How this works is you put in the number of items you are adding at once, and it will select all the elements less than that number. Basically if I put 5 it will select the first 5 items (zero-indexed).

Example:

`$("#content > .av:lt(5)").css("color", "red");`

You don't have to put in a hard-coded number 5. You count with a variable (i.e. `i++`) then just use `:lt("i")`;

Comment: It looks like he's adding several rows at once and any of them could need to be highlighted depending on the value of `avValue`. I don't think this solution would work in that case.

Comment: @cfs agree, that's what i want to achieve

Comment: @JonnySooter Your update doesn't account for the value of availbility

Comment: @cfs I don't understand what you're trying to say, what value?

Comment: just to note, everything has to by dynamic, no hardcoding

Comment: @JonnySooter The `.av` span should only have red text if the value of `availability` is 1

Comment: I was also thinking to add a new class to .box when avValue == 1 and then based on that if that class exists to something. but this doesn't work either. It is very strange. could that be something to do with async or caching ajax?